# how to automate the Alert from Java Security related alert - selenium web driver using Java

Tags: java, security, selenium-webdriver

Please suggest, how to automate the Security Alert during execution the applications

refer the sample screens[image]

[image]

need to click the Run Button and Allow Button from that picture, also this issues was Security checking by system, its not related to the Application, in this situation how to accept this Alert during the Execution

tries.alert.accept but its not working

-Prabu

Answer (score 2):

As these prompts are from the Java Plugin rather than the browser itself, accepting them is beyond the scope of the browser automatation provided by Selenium (it's very unlikely that Oracle offers a JavaScript API to accept one of these prompts, as that would also enable malicious code to circumvent that prompt, and thereby cause a security vulnerability).

What you can try is fixing the Applet in question by providing the [necessary manifest attributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/secman.html), or configure the Java Plugin to permit that Applet without prompts, for instance using [deployment rule sets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_rules.html).

Comment: neat except they want a cert to makea a deployment rule set ! expensive

Comment: Why? Can't you use a self signed cert, and install it into the appropriate trust store?

Comment: i was quoting the site. but if there is a workaround its good to know. I upvoted your answer